# which file to render and play in android youtube player

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

I am successfully integrate [YouTube Android Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/) for my apps. I am curious to know about which file is rendered in the player. Every single video file may have several formats like 320dpi,720dpi & etc.

If my users, is in lower bandwidth; can i choose the file format or the API automatically detects which version would be played in that situation and vice-verse. My code:

```
  public class YoutubeVideoActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements
        YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener, YouTubePlayer.OnFullscreenListener {

    Activity activity = YoutubeVideoActivity.this;

    public static final String API_KEY = "AIzaSyDN6Q9Pv4seQZqIcjB*********Po5k";
    // public static final String VIDEO_ID = "psY0Botpi84";

    public String new_id;
    private boolean fullscreen;
    private YouTubePlayerView playerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {

        super.onCreate(arg0);
        // Remove title bar
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_youtube_video);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String video_link = intent.getExtras().getString("video_link");

        try {
            new_id = video_link.substring("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v="
                    .length());
            if (new_id.equals("")) {
                IndepententTVUtils.showCustomAlert(activity,
                        "Data is not availble. Press back key",
                        R.drawable.ic_new_launcher);
            } else {
                playerView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtubeplayerview);
                playerView.initialize(API_KEY, this);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

            IndepententTVUtils.showCustomAlert(activity,
                    "Data is not availble", R.drawable.ic_new_launcher);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(Provider arg0,
            YouTubeInitializationResult arg1) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "To See this Video, Install Latest YouTube Application",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider arg0, YouTubePlayer player,
            boolean wasRestored) {

        player.setOnFullscreenListener(this);

        if (!wasRestored && new_id != null) {

            player.cueVideo(new_id);

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onFullscreen(boolean isFullscreen) {

        fullscreen = isFullscreen;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The player sets video quality automatically according to the users bandwidth or internet speed, if it was not so there would be an option specifying the setPlaybackQuality in player.
There are only restricted options to change the player settings that are 
[here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer)

Comment: thanks  ...where I found setPlaybackQuality ? How I get the confirmation of your  words "player sets video quality automatically according to the users bandwidth or internet speed"?